# How to convert figure in matlab to object?

Tags: matlab, object, figure

Sorry if my question wasn't fully understood...I will try to clarify it by describing my problem...

I have object (in binary image) almost curvey and long. I want to plot a line from its top point to its lowest point then after that either fill enclosed area between my curve and straight line to measure its area or finding the distance between every point in the curve and the line for same purpose... I know its easy to plot a line by using plot as follow:

```
imshow(fnnShrink)
hold on
plot([TLx , BRx ],[TLy ,BRy],'-', 'MarkerFaceColor' , 'b')
hold off
```

Which give me nice colored line (in figure of matlab), but the problem I couldnot perform any measurment on this line (its for showing only). Even when trying handler as one of friend here told me, it still give me the length of line only (not helpful).
One of solution I tried is to make a line by my self by setting pixel to 1 by using line equation and create new object line in image as follow:

```
m = (TLy - BRy) / (TLx - BRx); % Always Same
   for i = TLx : 1 : BRx
        fnnShrink(round(m * (i - TLx) + TLy) , round(i)) = 1;
        fTest(round(m * (i - TLx) + TLy) , round(i)) = 1;
    end
```

This solution work in some image if the distance (between upper point and lower one) (on X-axis) is relatively big, the problem is when the distance is very small (slope is negative) I got only discrete line and not continuous one (group of points between the upper and lower points)... that my problem.. and  please help me if you can...

Comment: Could you post the code that you have so far, did you try the function 'imline'? http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imline.html

Comment: Dear user, I think imline work as the same principle of plot...

Comment: No, `imline` lets you draw a line on an image and returns the position of the line. But now that you edited your question, it doesn't seem like what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, imshow, as all plotting function in matlab, does not only show the plot. It also returns a handle (the matlab equivalent of a pointer) to the object created. So, you just need

```
new_object = imshow(...)
```

instead of just imshow

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the question in any way.

Comment: you don't see how "an image IS AN object in matlab" is related to the question "how can i convert an image to object" ??? Really???

Comment: Dear blue_note , I have tried what you say but it just give me the length of the line in my case...

Comment: I don't see how using the handle to the image object created by `imshow` can give you the length of the line. It gives you control on things like the alpha-layer the size of the window etc. nothing related to high level features in the content of the image it is displaying.

Comment: OK, let me write to you what happen with me exactly to see if I understood you correctly, I wrote it in this way:                         NewL = imshow(fnnShrink) then the rest of plot function,  I got a variable NewL with one value inside it which represent the length of the line that I plot it. Is there different way to use this variable or object?

Comment: The question has changed completely since i gave this answer. The original question was "how can you get the object created by imshow". Anyway, normally the returned value is not just a number, it is an [image object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/the-image-object-and-its-properties.html). This object contains data related to the image(cdata, xdata, ydata), as well as the properties of the figure object.